# How can I delete an object from my stream

Tags: java

I have x amount of objects stored in my stream and the user can search for the object they would like to delete. After searching, I print the object and it's elements onto the screen and ask if that is the object they'd like to delete, prompting a yes/no confirmation. With confirmation, the object should be deleted and the stream of items should be printed again excluding the item that was just deleted (since well, it was deleted lol).
I ran into a problem where my code just stops running and does not print anything after the user confirms, I'm not sure why. I'm using `removeIf` since upon research that was what was recommended.

Main Class

```
else if (choice == 3){
            System.out.println("\nEnter the name of the movie you would like to delete (Case Sensitive): ");
            String search = scan.nextLine();

            Optional<Item> optionalItemToRemove = items.stream()
                    .map(x->{
                        if(x.getItems()==null){
                            return Collections.singletonList(x);
                        }
                        x.getItems().getItem().add(x);
                        return x.getItems().getItem();
                    })
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(search))
                    .peek(x-> x.setItems(null))//Peek exists mainly to support debugging
                    .findFirst();
            System.out.println(optionalItemToRemove.toString());

            System.out.println("Confirm Deletion? (Y/N)");
            String confirm = scan.nextLine();

            if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            if (optionalItemToRemove.isPresent()) {
                items.removeIf(itemToCheck -> itemToCheck.equals(optionalItemToRemove));

                System.out.println(items);
           }
            else return;
        }
        else return;
```

Item Class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Item {

        private String dataType;
        private String name;
        private int data;
        private String group;
        private Items items;
    
        @XmlElement
        public String getDataType(){
            return dataType;
        }
        public void setDataType(String dataType){
            this.dataType = dataType;
        }
    
        @XmlElement
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        @XmlElement
        public int getData(){
            return data;
        }
        public void setData(int data){
            this.data = data;
        }
    
        @XmlElement
        public String getGroup(){
            return group;
        }
        public void setGroup(String group){
            this.group = group;
        }
    
        public Items getItems() {
            return items;
        }
    
        public void setItems(Items items) {
            this.items = items;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return
                    "\n\tDataType: " + dataType +
                    "\n\tName: " + name +
                    "\n\tData: " + data +
                    "\n\tGroup: " + group +
                    "\n\tItems: " + items + "\n";
        }
    }
```

Items Class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
public class Items {
    private List<Item> item;

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<Item> getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<Item> itemList){
        this.item = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + item ;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (confirm == "y" || confirm == "Y")` -> `if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))`.

Comment: Can you explain what you think removeIf does? Can you use a debugger to see what is in your items list after you call removeIf?

Comment: It should remove all the elements of a list should a condition be true. That's how I understand it atleast

Comment: @tgdavies items list has a value of 0 after removeIf is called

Comment: To be precise, it evaluates a predicate (a function taking an item from the list and returning true or false) and removes any item where the predicate returns true. Your predicate is `item -> true`. Which items does that return true for?

Comment: My intention was for it to return true for the item that was searched, I'm guessing it returns true for all items?

Comment: Correct. The notation `item -> true` is like writing a function: `boolean func(Item item) { return true;}`, that is, it ignores the item it is supposed to be checking. You need to compare the item passed to the predicate with the item you want to delete, and only return true if they are the same.

Comment: @tgdavies I understand but I'm unsure how to do this. Here's what I tried `items.removeIf(x -> items.stream().forEach(item));`

Comment: I think the only problem now is that you are comparing an Item with an Optional<Item>. You need to be comparing each Item in the list (via `removeIf`) with the Item that you want to remove, not the Optional that contains it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time with the comparing aspect in all honesty

Comment: What aspect of comparing exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You have an `Optional<Item>` named `item` which contains the item that the user wants to remove (and might be an empty `Optional` if `search` didn't match the name of any item). A better name for `item` would be `optionalItemToRemove` to clarify what it is for.

You have a `List<Item>` named `items` which you want to remove `item` from.

We only want to do that if the Optional actually contains an Item, so we can say:

```
if (item.isPresent()) {
  // remove the item
  // because we know the item is present we can safely call item.get() to get the actual Item inside the Optional
}
```

To remove the item we can use `items.removeIf(...)`.

The argument to `removeIf` is a `Predicate<String>`. It is a function which is called once for each item in the `List`, and returns `true` if that item is to be deleted, and `false` if we want to keep it.

We want to delete the item which is stored in the Optional, so we need to write a function which returns true if the item passed to it is the item in the Optional.

Have a think and see whether you can write that function, i.e.

```
items.removeIf(itemToCheck -> ...)
```

Where the ellipsis is you need an expression which checks whether itemToCheck is the Item you want to delete.

Please let us know if there are parts of this answer you don't follow.

Try reading the Javadoc for the functions being used, and write some small test programs to help you understand what they do. It is easier to understand how something works in a very small program than trying to use it in your larger program before you completely understand what it does.

Comment: I have a general idea of what you're saying. I'm unsure where to call item.get(). For the removal process, I have this `items.removeIf(itemToCheck -> itemToCheck.equals(optionalItemToRemove));` The result of this doesn't remove the item that I want it to remove, but I do know that it's working to some extent since I can see that the item I want is being collected when I debug the program

Comment: Also `if(item.isPresent())` was not recognized, I had used `if(optionalItemToRemove.isPresent())` not sure if this may cause errors

Comment: Please update your question with your current code.